# How to download source code for a particular commit in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I would like to download (as zip) a particular commit in Bitbucket. Unfortunately I can not find any facility in the UI to do it.

(I've already found out that I can see the source by copy and pasting the short hash of the commit after the url: https://bitbucket.org/myname/myproject/src/) Is this manual way only to browse the source code of a particular commit?)

Comment: my answer was one year earlier than the accepted answer and it is same.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The url below should work. Just change required parts.

```
https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<reponame>/get/<commitCODE>.tar.gz
```

(without hypens)

Comment: Is there a way to provide credentials while calling this url? Since some of the repos are private in nature and needs login id and password of bitbucket to get access.

Comment: @AnudeepS You can use curl:
curl -s -S --user username:apppassword -L -O  <URL>

Answer (score 42):

https://bitbucket.org/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/get/COMMITNUMBER.tar.gz

note the uppercase in the URL. you will need to change them COMMITNUMBER can be found under commit for that specific commit.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to add the Tag for the particular commit and then you can Download it as a zip.

1. Login to bitbucket.org
2. Navigate to a particular Repository
3. From the left pane click on Commits
4. Click on the row for your desired commit
5. Add a tag
6. Click on Downloads from left pane
7. Click on Tags and download the zip

Comment: this is an excellent answer to this question and still relevant today in late 2023

Answer (score 3):

To download a particular commit in Bitbucket go to : 
 Repositories -> Select repository
click on Downloads --> Branches. 
You will find all the commits made to the repository. Select which commit you want to download. To download as a zip file, click zip under download column.

Comment: This is not possible in 2021. Maybe they removed this feature from BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enter in Terminal "git checkout COMMIT-ID"

Replace COMMIT-ID with the commit id in your repo.